# Сколько будет объектных модулей?

Tags: c++

Предположим, есть два заголовочных файла, header1.h и header2.h, и, допустим, есть три файла .cpp - code1, code2, code3 примерно подобного содержания:

code1.cpp:

```
 #include "header1.h"  
  #include "header2.h" 
  //some code...
```

code2.cpp:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

code3.cpp:

```
 //some code
```

Вопрос, сколько будет сгенерировано объектных файлов и как Вы подсчитали количество объектных модулей?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3, по одному на каждый cpp файл. А кол-во h файлов значения не имеет. Ну кроме тех случаев, когда h файл просто имеет такое расширение, но заголовочным не является.

Comment: Т.е. несмотря на то что code1.cpp и code2.cpp включают один и тот же хедер, они будут в разных объектных модулях?

Comment: Ключевой момент - просто примите тот факт, что include просто вставляет файл в указанное место. Именно обычная, механическая вставка без какой то логики. Потом уже препроцессор проходит и разбирается с дерективами `ifdef`, `define` и подобными.

Конечно, современные компиляторы умеют делать определенный анализ и ускорять этот процесс, не включая файл понапрасну.

Для разминки рекомендую изучить вывод `g++ -E filename.cpp` либо `cl /E filename.cpp` - можно увидеть результат препроцессора. Иногда очень полезно, если в коде есть сложные макросы.

Comment: @SoloMio, компилятор делает (если его просят делать объектные файлы) строго один .o из каждого .cpp

.h файлы *текстуально* добавляются в .cpp на стадии компиляции.

Можно сделать загрузочный модуль (в винде .exe) из нескольких .cpp минуя .o

А Вы руками компилятор с разными флагами и комбинациями файлов позапускайте и посмотрите какие новые файлы появляются.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо Вам всем большое, обязательно поэкспериментирую.